# Letsencrypt SSL certificate on staging and production servers

Tags: django, wordpress, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

Suppose my domain is `example.com` being managed by AWS Route53.

I have an EC2 instance serving a Wordpress site (production) at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and example.com.

I also have a staging server for a Django app at development.example.com.

Once I have done my testing for the Django app, I will be taking down the Wordpress site and replace it with my Django site. In the end, I will have one production server for Django and another for internal testing on the staging server.

Will I need a separate LetsEncrpyt certificates for the two servers?

I don't want to bring down my current Wordpress site as my app is not really ready yet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need different certs, but letencrypt is free and renews automatically if you use the certbot app.
Assuming the server has a standard port 80 virtualhost in either apache or nginx.

prod server:

```
sudo certbot -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

staging:

```
sudo certbot -d development.example.com
```

certbot installs and configures your virtualhosts, so there is no reason not to have multiple certs.